# MVC 3 Client Side Validation - Specify Date Range for validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I am using declaring a partial class with my Model to customize the validation. I wish to apply validation to the ExpiryDate field so that it is in between the range of Today's date <= x <= StorageDate. I got no idea how to implement this.. I have gone through several examples but could not find something I need... Following is my partial class:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(FoodMetaData))]
public partial class FOOD
{
    [Bind(Exclude = "FoodID")]
    public class FoodMetaData
    {
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a name")]
        public object FoodName { get; set; }            

        public object StorageDate { get; set; }

        public object ExpiryDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I need something like Range[today's date, storagedate] but I cant get anything similar.

Please help... appreciate any feedback... Thanks...

Comment: may be this will help http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2011/01/25/asp-net-mvc-3-integrating-with-the-jquery-ui-date-picker-and-adding-a-jquery-validate-date-range-validator.aspx

Comment: hi, i tried that too, but i get error where i cant specify the min date as a "dynamic" date (today date) and also not able to set the max date using the StorageDate which is another variable in the class...